# MERN this same query different output from remote server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I have a problem with my MERN app. On my localhost everything is correct but since is hosted on remote server db return different data.

When I sent query http://:8080/getreports?date=40-2020

(actually whatever server get afte getreports? return always this same)

server return all records from db.

When I use this same query on localhost server return me records where date is equal to 40-2020.
(correct behave)

below me server code

Thanks for help

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();
const apiPort = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const path = require("path");

const Record = require("./models/record-model");

const db = require("./db");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "MongoDB connection error:"));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "..", "build")));

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "..", "build", "index.html"));
});

app.post("/reports", (req, res) => {
  const body = req.body;

  if (!body) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      success: false,
      error: "You must provide a record",
    });
  }

  const record = new Record(body);

  if (!record) {
    return res.status(400).json({ success: false, error: err });
  }

  record
    .save()
    .then(() => {
      return res.status(201).json({
        success: true,
        message: "Record created!",
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      return res.status(400).json({
        error,
        message: "Record not created!",
      });
    });
});

app.get("/getreports", async (req, res) => {
  await Record.find({ "WW-YYYY": `${req.query.date}` }, (err, reports) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).json({ success: false, error: err });
    }
    if (!reports.length) {
      return res
        .status(404)
        .json({ success: false, error: `Reports not found` });
    }
    return res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: reports });
  }).catch((err) => console.log(err));
});


app.listen(apiPort, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${apiPort}`));
```

Comment: app.get("/getreports", async (req, res) => {
  await Record.find({ "WW-YYYY": `${req.query.date}` } this path receiving parameter from url and search moongodb to return record. The problem is this setup work ok on my localhost , filtering everything correctly. When its hosted to ubuntu server each time return all records , doesn't matter what parameter you sent

Comment: getreports?date=40-2020  is url query I sent to API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to shear solution for my problem. The problem was server couldn't recognize template string for parameter in html query. On local machine everything was ok but on remote server moongo behave default, like when you search empty object, return all records in database.

I just simple remove template string to simple variable and works, this is what i did in code:

await Record.find({ "WW-YYYY": **`${req.query.date}`** }, (err, reports)

to

await Record.find({ "WW-YYYY": **req.query.date** }, (err, reports)

maybe this will help someone in future.

Regards,
Damian